# How to set metric for connection using 3G / ppp

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, routing

My linux device has ethernet, wifi and 3G network. The /etc/network/interfaces contains entries for eth0 and wlan0. I use ifup/ifdown to enable/disable those devices. 
For ppp0 I use pon/poff and an extra configuration file. There is no entry for ppp0 in /etc/network/interfaces.

Sometimes eth0 or wlan0 are not available, ppp0 is the fallback in that case. Thus I want the following metrics:

```
eth0 metric 1    // done in /etc/network/interfaces
wlan0 metric 2   // done in /etc/network/interfaces
ppp0 metric 3
```

Where is the right place for the metric of ppp0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ip route` command to configure the metric settings for all 3 interfaces (or just ppp0, leaving the already defined metrics intact). Here is an excerpt from a [good explanation](http://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/#Routes%20with%20different%20metric) of the command syntax:

> Routes with different metric
>
> ip route add ${address}/${mask} via ${gateway} metric ${number}
>   Examples:
>
> ```
> ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 metric 5
> ip route add 192.168.2.0 dev ppp0 metric 10
> ```
>
> If there are several routes to the same network with different metric
>   value, the one with the lowest metric will be preferred.
>
> Important part of this concept is that when an interface goes down,
>   routes that would be rendered useless by this event disappear from the
>   routing table (see the Connected Routes section), and the system will
>   fall back to higher metric routes.
>
> This feature is commonly used to implement backup connections to
>   important destinations.